# Java error eclipse on list sort

Tags: java

I have an error on the following line:

```
Collections.sort(l);
```

Can you explain why?

This is program code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Esame{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<Studente> l=new ArrayList<Studente>();
        BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String cognome = b.readLine();
        while(!cognome.equals("")){
            System.out.println("inserire nome");
            String nome = b.readLine();
            System.out.println("inserire matricola");
            String matricola = b.readLine();
            Studente s = new Studente(nome, cognome, matricola);
            l.add(s);
            System.out.println("inserire cognome");
            cognome = b.readLine();
        }
        b.close();
        Collections.sort(l);
        Iterator<Studente> i=l.iterator();
        PrintStream p=new PrintStream(new File("uscita.txt"));
        while(i.hasNext()){
            p.println(i.hasNext());
        }
        p.close();
    }

}

class Studente{

    protected String nome,cognome;
    protected int matricola;

    public Studente(String nome,String cognome,String matricola){
        this.nome=nome;
        this.cognome=cognome;
        this.matricola=Integer.parseInt(matricola);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "\n NOME:  "+nome+"Cognome:  "+cognome+"MATRICOLA: "+matricola;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object x) {
         Studente p = (Studente) x;
         return cognome.compareTo(p.cognome);
    }
}
```

Comment: Print the Console output, so we can read the Exception please.

Comment: What is the error? Is it stack trace then please post, or if its an eclipse error than post a screenshot

Comment: I have try with @override but,  does not change anything: the error is this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Studente>)

 at Esame.main(Esame.java:31)

Comment: class Studente must implement Comparable<Studente>, then only sorting works

Answer (score 3):

You can just `implements Comparable<T>` to fix the problem, or you can pass a `Comparator` to the `sort` method, like:

```
Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<Studente>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Studente o1, Studente o2) {
                // some kind of comparation
                return o1.matricola - o2.matricola;
            }
        });
```

This way your class doesn't need to implement Comparable interface

Answer (score 2):

Changes

1.) Implement `Comparable` interface in Student Class

```
public class Studente implements Comparable<Studente>{
}
```

2.) Change overridden method `compareTo`

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Studente o) {
        Studente p = (Studente) o;
        return cognome.compareTo(p.cognome);
    }
```

From Javadoc,

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the
>   natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the list must
>   implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the
>   list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not
>   throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).

Refer [Collections#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) for more details

Answer (score 2):

```
 class Studente implements Comparable&lt;Studente&gt;{

    protected String nome,cognome;
    protected int matricola;

    public Studente(String nome,String cognome,String matricola){
       this.nome=nome;
        this.cognome=cognome;
        this.matricola=Integer.parseInt(matricola);
    }

    public String toString(){
      return "\n NOME:  "+nome+"Cognome:  "+cognome+"MATRICOLA: > "+matricola;
    }

    public int compareTo(Studente x) {
       //how to compare
       return 0;
    }
```

you have to make you class implement comparable.

Comment: you will have to insert the logic to compare and return 0,1,-1 depending on the compare result.

Answer (score 1):

your class Studente has to implement the `Comparable` interface in order to be sorted!

Otherwise `.sort(...)` does not know how to compare the `Studente` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `Arraylist` to just `List`.

`ArrayList<Studente> l=new ArrayList<Studente>();`

Should be

`List<Studente> l=new ArrayList<Studente>();`

Collections.sort`method accepts an`List`and not an`ArrayList`

See [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Snippet from Spec

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the
>   natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the list must
>   implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the
>   list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not
>   throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).

Your `Studente` class should implement `Comparable` interface for your `sort` to work correctly.

`Implement` `Comparable` interface in `Studente` class

```
class Studente implements Comparable<Studente>{

    protected String nome,cognome;
    protected int matricola;

    public Studente(String nome,String cognome,String matricola){
        this.nome=nome;
        this.cognome=cognome;
        this.matricola=Integer.parseInt(matricola);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "\n NOME:  "+nome+"Cognome:  "+cognome+"MATRICOLA: "+matricola;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Studente o) {
        // Logic for compare has to go here
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Parker_Halo changing both `List` and implements `comparable` should fix his problem.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty Bounds mismatch wont happen if OP implements `comparable` interface correctly.

Comment: @SajanChandran yes now he'll be fine ;)